# New Router with AngularJS 1.4: How to get FormController object

Tags: angularjs

I'm working on a new project, where I’ve been using new router configuration. I know it's still in the beta version. The only problem I have is how to **get FormController object**.

Since new router configuration is using **controllerAs** syntax out-of-the-box, I set the name attribute on the form tag. But then I get form value in the controller **undefined**.

I’m familiar with the solution for controllerAs syntax as described here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/3115, but if add ng-controller directive in my html, then the controller gets instantiated two times.

*Javascript*

```
function SearchController() {
    this.searchForm;
}
```

*Form*

```
<form name="search.searchForm">
   form controls
</form>
```

The question is, how to access [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) object to get validation informations of the form?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you're using it in template as intended. Then

```
<form name="appCtrlIdentifier.searchForm">
```

may work (as well as `$parent.searchForm`). FormController assignment to the scope indeed won't work specifically with `search.searchForm`, though there are no problems for ordinary bindings, route controllers seem to be pretty messed up for now.

> I know it's still in the beta version.

More of alpha rather than beta, '0.5.x' truthfully represent its current state. New router isn't nearly ready for production, there are a lot of issues that will reveal themselves even in usual conditions. My guess is that it is one of them.